# is there any improvement in performance if we did indexed primaryKey with another column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

hello i am new to indexing. Is there any improvement in performance if we did indexing the primary key with other column? 
ex:

```
CREATE INDEX users_cmp_id_idx ON user  (cmp_id, uname);
```

where cmp_id is primary key and uname is not null.

Comment: Are you likely to search by just the name?

Comment: If cmp_id is the primary key, there's probably no need to explicitly include it in the index.

Comment: Here is an excellent resource to study:  http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 0):

Since CMP_ID is your primary key, it is unique. You won't have any performance improvement when creating this new index... and you will loose some performance in insertions.
If you need to do some lookups just by uname, create an index on uname.